# How to save data in django without method post and forms?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save data, but i don't want to use method post or forms there's some way to do it?.
I can do something like this?

```
class Number(models.Model):
    data = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Number

def x(request):
   #something different happened to (if request method ==POST, GET,etc)
   number = Number.objects.create(data=1)
   #now something different happened and the view automatically do something like this.
   number = number +1
   number.save()
```

Can i do this with django? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes. You could do whatever you want even if it is a GET request.
Could you elaborate on your use-case?
Here's a quick dirty guide to GET vs POST https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests

Just don't send any sensitive information in there. If you're just gonna update Number as a view count or something, go for it.